# error in uploading multy files in the same table

Tags: php, mysql

i have this problem when i upload images in the database . when i insert the query i have 3 row in just one click . this is HTML file :

```
 <form action="my_parser.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
 <input type="file" name="file_array[]">
 <input type="file" name="file_array[]">
 <input type="file" name="file_array[]">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload all files"> 
 </form>
```

and this is my PHP code :

```
<?
include "../include/config.php";

?>

<?
 if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
     $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
     $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
     $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
     $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
     $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error']; 
     $image1 = $name_array[0];

        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
         if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], 
            "test_uploads/".$name_array[$i])){ 
            echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";

            $add = mysql_query("insert into nn values ('        ','$image1','','')");

             echo "<img src='test_uploads/$image1'>";
             } else
              { echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>"; 
            }
             } 
            } 
            ?>
```

in data base the table nn have this column . id - image1 - image2 - image3.
thank you

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure because your user parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** be putting `$_POST` data directly into the query. This creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clean this up a bit.

Let's setup the database connection. We're moving to `mysqli` for this example. Then we'll handle moving the file, and storing the file path in the database.

```
$conn = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])):
    $id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : false;
    if($id):
        $file_array = $_FILES['file_array'];
        for($i = 0; $i < count($file_array['tmp_name']); $i++):
            if(move_uploaded_file($file_array['tmp_name'][$i], 'test_uploads/'.$file_array['name'][$i])):
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into nn values('', ?, '', '')");
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $file_array['name'][$i]);
                if($stmt->execute()):
                    echo $file_array['name'][$i].' has been uploaded successfully.';
                else:
                    echo 'Failed to upload '.$file_array['name'][$i].'. Please check the file and try again!';
                    return false;
                endif;
            endif;
        endfor;
    endif;
endif;
```

There's no reason to create all those messy variables. We've moved to MySQLI which is *currently* supported, and we've used a prepared statement to ensure that the name of the image isn't something malicious that could be detrimental to our application.

**Resources**

- [moving from mysql to mysqli](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi)
- [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
- [mysqli bind param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)